# How to restore Unity Buttons style to default?

Tags: unity

Trying to compile Ardour software I installed all the libraries required. During this process something messed up the buttons in Unity. Its very easy to see the problem in the Firefox panels buttons.  The buttons are now like old fashion; very straight lines (like in Windows 3.11 LOL). What could have done that and how can I restore the original Unity look and feel ?

Here's some images:
Firefox, this same window, with ugly tab buttons:: 
[image: Firefox with ugly tab buttons]

In this window, the buttons are all old fashioned:: 
[image: Another example]

I have tried:
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge  light-themes
sudo apt-get install  light-themes

Then restart my system, but no way... Its still the same;

Here's the packages I installed and that I think one of them is responsible for the mess:

Package         Base Version    Download

**libsndfile**  1.0.25  ardour.org/files/deps/libsndfile-1.0.25.tar.gz

**gnomecanvas** 2.30.3    ardour.org/files/deps/libgnomecanvas-2.30.3.tar.gz

**libsigc++**   2.2.10    ardour.org/files/deps/libsigc++-2.2.10.tar.bz2

**cairo**   2.2.10    ardour.org/files/deps/cairo-1.12.14.tar.xz

**gtk+** (for X11)  2.24.18 ardour.org/files/deps/gtk+-2.24.18-x11.tar.bz2

**lrdf**    0.5.0   ardour.org/files/deps/liblrdf-0.5.0.tar.gz

After this problem, I've reinstalled gnomecanvas and libgtk* (using Synaptic and marking them for reinstallation). But the problem still persists.

Well, now I have an example of how those buttons where like when they where right. This printscreen is from my other Ubuntu computer:

[image: Good buttons, correct layout]

Comment: Did you try reloading a theme? (from Appearances).

Comment: Could provide a link to a screenshot?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong in either picture... Except that firefox is using radience. What theme do you want to use?

Comment: Well.... maybe it's my eyes... Or maybe the fonts are a little bit bigger than before and for that I may find that the buttons are different. If this is the case, how could I set the font for something a little smaller ?

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/Pdg8Gc8.png) is what mine looks like.

Comment: Thats it, Seth. Mine used to be like that. I uploaded an example last night.

Comment: Oh, I see now. If you right click on the desktop and open "Change desktop wallpaper" is your theme set to "Ambiance"?

Comment: Yes, it is... but the "annoyance" still continues ;-))